# IN with a list of numbers (BigQuery + GoogleSheetS)

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I have access to BigQuery through work, but no write access. Just read.

So I have a bunch of integers in a GoogleSheets, one column (~400):

| User. |
| --- |
| 332321 |
| 031230 |
| 938101 |

These numbers all correspond to a specific value in a table in BQ, but unfortunately, they aren't easily queried, as they are the result of multiple queries, etc.

So my dilemma. How can I take the column of integers from GoogleSheets and then use it *in* a query (say, in a WHERE clause)? My only suggestion has been to get write access: https://supermetrics.com/blog/bigquery-query-google-sheets

Comment: have you tried the community wiki answer below?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an external table in BigQuery using your Google Sheet data for you to be able to query it in BigQuery. However, as you have already mentioned, the only solution for this is to get write/create access permission to BigQuery which is also mentioned in your provided reference --> https://supermetrics.com/blog/bigquery-query-google-sheets.

In addition, you may refer to [Query Google Drive Data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive) documentation as it conatains more details about the permissions needed for BigQuery and Google Drive before you can create/query an external table in BigQuery and also the actual creation and query execution.

> **BigQuery permissions**
>
> At a minimum, the following permissions are required to create and query an external table in BigQuery.
>
> - `bigquery.tables.create`
> - `bigquery.tables.getData`
> - `bigquery.jobs.create`

> **Drive permissions**
>
> At a minimum, to query external data in Drive you must be granted `View` access to the Drive file linked to the external table.